# accidentally removed show desktop button in linux Mint 17 Maya

Tags: linux-mint

I accidentally removed the desktop icon from the menubar.  How can I restore it?  I'm using Linux Mint 17 Maya.  Iḿ new to this so I don know whAT TO DO

Answer (score 2):

The method used to recover the Show Desktop button depends on the desktop environment.

If you use KDE, right-click the panel, go to the `Panel Options` menu, then unlock widgets, if necessary.  Then, click the Panel Tool Box button at the far right of the panel and select `Add Widgets` from the box that appears above the panel.  Scroll until you find the Show Desktop button, and drag it onto the panel.  You can then close the configuration window and lock the widgets.

In the Cinnamon environment, right-click the panel and enable panel edit mode.  Right click the panel again and select `Add Applets to Panel`.  Locate the Show Desktop applet, select it, and click the `Add to Panel` button.

If you use XFCE, right click the panel, enter the Panel menu, and `select Add New Items...`.  Locate and select the Show Desktop applet then click `Add'.  Then close the Add New Items window.